# Overriding Base file template file

Tags: magento2, overriding, theme-overriding

There is a file that is used asynchronously in the front end called listing.html at the following path.

`vendor/magento/module-catalog/view/base/web/template/product/list/listing.html`

It is used by the recently viewed to render recently viewed items.

I want to override this file in my Vendor/Theme/ folder.

I have already tried the following locations

`design/frontend/FossilGroup/default/Magento_Catalog/templates/product/list/
design/frontend/FossilGroup/default/Magento_Catalog/web/template/product/list/
design/frontend/FossilGroup/default/Magento_Catalog/web/templates/product/list/
design/base/FossilGroup/default/Magento_Catalog/template/product/list/
design/base/FossilGroup/default/Magento_Catalog/templates/product/list/
design/base/FossilGroup/Magento_Catalog/template/product/list/
design/base/FossilGroup/Magento_Catalog/templates/product/list/
design/web/FossilGroup/default/Magento_Catalog/templates/product/list/
design/web/FossilGroup/default/Magento_Catalog/template/product/list/`

Version: **Magento 2.2**

Comment: which magento version you are using ? because up to 2.1.6 there is no listing.html available on path you provided.

Comment: I'm using Version 2.2.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Copy this file

```
 vendor/magento/module-catalog/view/base/web/template/product/list/listing.html
```

Paste it here.

```
  app/design/frontend/Vendor/theme/Magento_Catalog/web/template/product/list/listing.html
```

Comment: I've tried this. This is one of the examples above.

Comment: This is the right way to do it, i think you might have issue with your layout file or block file.

Comment: Try this link https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/216632/magento-2-2-1-how-to-override-recently-viewed-template

Comment: This is the correct path! I just needed to run the command php bin/magento setup:upgrade after adding the file.

Comment: I don't have xml layout so without layout how can i do this ?